# about custom UItextField on iphone including delegates

Tags: iphone, objective-c

actually i want to create custom class for textfield and in that same class handling of all things like delegate,any other properties also.from controller only i need to call just a single method of that class.

Answer (score 0):

You mean using the textfield delegate in your own class so you can use the Textfield methods?

Try adding  `< UITextFieldDelegate >`  in your .h file like:

```
@interface YourClass : NSObject <UITextFieldDelegate>
```

Hope this is what you're looking for.

Comment: Wouldnt you need to subclass UITextField ... hmm the question is very confusing ....

Comment: actually i want to create custom class for textfield and in that same class handling of all things like delegate,any other properties also.from controller only i need to call just a single method of that class.

Comment: hope you will get my question